# After sending TCP data, measure time until TCP ACK has been received

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, networkstream

When I send some data over an open tcp connection, using `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream`, how can I check whether the receiver has replied with a TCP ACK for the last packet?

What happens if the receiver does not send an ACK, is there an exception i could catch to detect this?

My goal is to log the time between sent packets and received ACK, and to log when there is a delay caused by lost pakets.

Example:

```
using (TcpClient  client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1",2000))
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.ASCII))
while (true)
{
    writer.Write("test");
    writer.Flush(); // this does nothing, NetworkStream.Flush is a NoOp

    // do other stuff
}
```

After writer.Write(), how can I determine whether the data is still in the kernel buffer, or has been removed because the network interface received an ACK?

- The tcp connection has to remain open indefinitely, I cannot close it.
- `NetworkStream.Flush()` or the associated `StreamReader.Flush()` [is not implemented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) and will return immediately.
- I know that the receiver could send an explicit reply message which I could check. However in this case the protocol cannot be changed.
- I am also aware that I can reduce delays when sending small amounts of data by setting [`TcpClient.NoDelay=true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.nodelay(v=vs.110).aspx). However this still does not tell me whether an ACK has been received.

Is there any way to check from c# whether an ack has been received, or how quick it has been recieved?

Comment: More importantly, why do you feel you need to check? If the receiver does not acknowledge the transmission, TCP will retransmit; if that fails, you'll get an `IOException` and the connection will break. As a reliable protocol, TCP already implements checks to ensure all sent data is received.

Comment: I mainly want to check for logging purposes. I want to log how fast the ack has been sent; and if there are retransmissions, I want to log those too, so I can later determine the cause for delays.

Comment: That's the kind of thing that's much better handled with a packet sniffer like Wireshark, not internally in your application. (And no, I'm not aware of any managed interface that would allow you to actually get that information in-process.) The whole point of `NetworkStream` is to abstract away from that and present the entire transmission as an uninterrupted, in-order stream.

Comment: Also, tracking such things in the app will require this app to have maximal  permissions possible, which is barely a good style. There are lots of more conventional methods to check the connection quality, from `ping` to Cisco Netflow. Wireshark is an option too, especially because it has an API.